# Empty byte array when using NextBytes

Tags: c#, random, .net-core

Consider I have the following code:

```
public sealed class SimpleRandomProvider : IRandomProvider
{
    private static readonly Lazy<Random> RandomHolder = new Lazy<Random>(() => new Random());

    public void NextBytes(byte[] buffer)
    {
        RandomHolder.Value.NextBytes(buffer);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, everytime I call `NextBytes` in `System.Random` `buffer` gets filled with empty bytes:

[image: Screen cast]

What is strange, first `X` (about 100) calls of `NextBytes` works just fine.

What is happening? **May it be a bug in .Net Core**?

The code that invokes generation:

```
do
{
    randomProvider.NextBytes(bytes);
    bytes[bytes.Length - 1] &= 0x7F;
    result = new BigInteger(bytes);
} while (result >= maxExclusive || result.Equals(BigInteger.One) ||
            result.Equals(BigInteger.Zero));
```

It is used to generate `BigInteger` below specified `maxExclusive`.
THe snippet avoid is called 100-200 times before it starts to generates buffer filled with zeroes (during unit test running).

**Edit**:

you can download my project: https://github.com/pwasiewicz/big-prime-number
- then run test - it should fail due to InvalidOperationException that is thrown only when buffer is empty.

When tests are runned one-by-one. But running them all (Run All in VS)  causes exception.

Comment: Try showing the contents of this byte array in some other way, like manually converting it to a string or something and inspecting that. The debugger visualizer has some bugs itself, this may be one of them.

Comment: Unfortunately - no. I have checked that -  I have tried to convert it to string and checking it with LINQ: `var isEmpty = buffer.All(v => v == 0);`.
Unit tests don't pass - I wrote a test that fills buffer until it contains any non-zero number..

Comment: Your code is working fine for me

Comment: Can you add the caller code, please?

Comment: @GuruStron added.

Comment: `bytes` is an ordinary array, nothing fancy?

Comment: @GuruStron yep. I am trying right now to create a separate project with minimal setup to reproduce issue.

Comment: @GuruStron you can download my project and run tests.

Comment: Issue seems to be realted to... multithread access.

Answer (score 2):

It turned out, that multithread access to `NextBytes` was problem:

```
private static readonly Lazy<Random> RandomHolder = new Lazy<Random>(() => new Random());
private static readonly object Access = new object();

public void NextBytes(byte[] buffer)
{
    lock (Acces)
        RandomHolder.Value.NextBytes(buffer);
}
```